# Add UTM to cloud pages

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, cloudpage

I want to pull the UTM fields from my cloud pages into the data extension. Do you think this amp script is good?

Thanks for your help.

```
%%[
SET @UTM_Source = RequestParameter('utm_source') 
SET @UTM_Medium = RequestParameter('utm_medium')
]%%
UTM source:
%%=v(@UTM_Source)=%%
<br>

UTM medium:
%%=v(@UTM_Medium)=%%
```

Answer (score 0):

To insert/upsert to a DE you'd have to use the [UpsertData](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/upsertdata.htm) ampscript function. Request parameter would be used to retrieve. When using Upsert Data ensure your DE has a primary key.